# NuGet packages restoration failed with error code 127 when building a Xamarin.iOS project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, nuget, xamarin-studio, nuget-package-restore

I'm trying to build a Xamarin.iOS project in Xamarin Studio. Nuget packages restoration is enabled but during any build I get the following error:

> /.nuget/NuGet.targets: Error: Command 'mono --runtime=v4.0.30319
>   "/.nuget/NuGet.exe" install "/ProjectName/packages.config" -source ""
>   -RequireConsent -solutionDir "/" exited with code: 127. (ProjectName)

Running the same command from the terminal gives no issues and works absolutely fine with the following output message:

> Restoring NuGet packages... To prevent NuGet from downloading packages
>   during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the
>   Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing
>   packages'.

.nuget/NuGet.exe and .nuget/NuGet.targets are up to date. With the disabled nuget restore at the project .csproj file compilation works just fine.

Please advise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exit code: 127  = "command not found"

Does running that following cmd really work from the ***base*** solution directory?

```
mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 "/.nuget/NuGet.exe" install "/ProjectName/packages.config" -source "" -RequireConsent -solutionDir "/"
```

- Mono not being able to find the CIL exe would result in an exit code of 2, but I am assuming it is not finding mono correctly...

If you type `which mono` is it found in `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin` ?

Try :

```
sudo ln /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/mono /usr/bin
```

And retry from Xamarin Studio.

Ref: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/43192/os-x-10-11-el-capitan-beta-and-xamarin-compiler-error-127

Comment: CTPAX-MBP:projectfolder astrakh$ which mono
/usr/local/bin/mono | it seems that I have mono 4.0.4 installed but I'm not sure how to force targets to use mono 4.0.4 not 4.0.3

Comment: I was able to edit the version to use but it didn't help, same error. The issue is that the same command could be successfully executed vie terminal

Comment: the output is the following: ln: /usr/bin/mono: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 3):

With @RobertN's help  I was able to locate the error and configured nuget's build target correctly to use proper mono. I specified full path to mono and it works now.

Was:

```
<NuGetCommand Condition=" '$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT' ">mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 "$(NuGetExePath)"</NuGetCommand>
```

Now:

```
<NuGetCommand Condition=" '$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT' ">/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mono --runtime=v4.0 "$(NuGetExePath)"</NuGetCommand>
```

EDIT1: but the most proper way is to create a link to mono and msc commands by disabling System Integrity Protection in recovery mode:

```
csrutil disable
```

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/43192/os-x-10-11-el-capitan-beta-and-xamarin-compiler-error-127#latest

Then restart and run those commands:

```
sudo ln /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/mcs /usr/bin/
sudo ln /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/mono /usr/bin/
```